# Null check operator errors

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

I could swear that when I ran this program it was fine until I hot reload and restart and now, I get the error: "Null check operator used on a null value", but I cannot remove anything now because everything there has helped me with other errors, I am confused and tired, I don't know what to do now.

this is the error;

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
I/flutter ( 5909): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build
I/flutter ( 5909): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init Localization Delegate
I/flutter ( 5909): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init provider

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyApp MyApp:file:///D:/StudioProjects/task_masters/lib/main.dart:22:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      getProportionateScreenWidth (package:task_masters/utils/sizes.dart:57:44)
#1      TextThemes.textTheme (package:task_masters/themes/theme.dart:65:21)
#2      AppTheme.lightTheme (package:task_masters/themes/theme.dart:11:29)
#3      MyApp.build (package:task_masters/main.dart:35:23)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5541:49)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5471:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2895:19)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:984:21)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:978:7)
#16     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 4 of 1151 libraries in 403ms (compile: 41 ms, reload: 156 ms, reassemble: 101 ms).
```

This is the relevant error-causing widget according to the error, i.e. "MyApp" class in the main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: const [Locale('en')],
    path: 'assets/translations',
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
    startLocale: const Locale('en'),
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Task Masters',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme(context),
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      locale: context.locale,
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack(specifically "getProportionateScreenWidth" in "sizes.dart" and "theme: AppTheme.lightTheme(context)" in "MaterialApp(" of "main.dart":

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// const num figmaDesignWidth = 428;
// const num figmaDesignHeight = 926;
// const num figmaDesignStatusBar = 0;
//
// MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQueryData.fromView(
//     WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.single);
//
// double getWidth(num percentage) {
//   return mediaQueryData.size.width * percentage / figmaDesignWidth;
// }
//
// double getHeight(num percentage) {
//   num statusBar = mediaQueryData.viewPadding.top;
//   num bottomBar = mediaQueryData.viewPadding.bottom;
//   num screenHeight = mediaQueryData.size.height - statusBar - bottomBar;
//   return screenHeight * percentage / (figmaDesignHeight - figmaDesignStatusBar);
// }
//
// double getAdaptSize(num percentage) {
//   var height = getHeight(percentage);
//   var width = getWidth(percentage);
//   return height < width ? height : width;
// }
//
// double getFontSize(num percentage) {
//   return getAdaptSize(percentage);
// }

class SizeConfig {
  MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData?.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData?.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData?.orientation;
  }
}

//Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double? screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  //926 is the layout height that designer uses
  return (inputHeight / 926.0) * screenHeight!;
}

//Get the proportionate width as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double? screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  //428 is the layout width that designer uses
  return (inputWidth / 428.0) * screenWidth!;
}
```

the other stacks are from "theme.dart" class, i.e. "TextTheme.textTheme" and "AppTheme.lightTheme":

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../constants.dart';
import '../utils/sizes.dart';

class AppTheme {
  static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
      colorScheme: primaryColorScheme,
      textTheme: TextThemes.textTheme(primaryColorScheme),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: primaryColorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: primaryColorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
        titleTextStyle: TextThemes
            .textTheme(primaryColorScheme)
            .displayMedium,
      ),
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: primaryColorScheme.primary,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          ),
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
            vertical: -4,
            horizontal: -4,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
      ),
      outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          side: BorderSide(
            color: PrimaryColors.blueGray100,
            width: getProportionateScreenWidth(1),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(getProportionateScreenWidth(10)),
          ),
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
            vertical: -4,
            horizontal: -4,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
      ),
      dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
        thickness: 1,
        space: 1,
        color: PrimaryColors.indigo50,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextThemes {
  static TextTheme textTheme(ColorScheme colorScheme) =>
      TextTheme(
        bodyLarge: TextStyle(
          color: PrimaryColors.black900,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(17), // 17.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
        bodyMedium: TextStyle(
          color: PrimaryColors.gray600,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(15), //15.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
        bodySmall: TextStyle(
          color: PrimaryColors.black900,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10), //10.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),

        //Label Text Task Master
        displayMedium: TextStyle(
          color: colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(40), //40.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Marcellus SC',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
        headlineLarge: TextStyle(
          color: colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(30), //30.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        ),
        headlineMedium: TextStyle(
          color: colorScheme.onErrorContainer,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(26), //26.fSize
          fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        ),

        // Title text style
        titleLarge: TextStyle(
          color: PrimaryColors.blueGray40001,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(20), //20.fSize,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),

        titleMedium: TextStyle(
          color: PrimaryColors.blueGray40001,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(16), //16.fSize,
          fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
        titleSmall: TextStyle(
          color: colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(14), //14.fSize,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your SizeConfig class contains only nullable values and doesn't seem  to be initialized before usage.

Try adding `SizeConfig().init(context)` before returning in your AppTheme/TextTheme functions